# When is it necessary to run ConTeXt multiple times?

Tags: context, performance

I am developing a server-side app for rendering PDF-documents for end users with `ConTeXt` with LMTX engine. Speed and throughput are essential to my task. I found that using `--once` option for compiling increases speed manyfold. The result seems the same. I know that it may be required to run ConTeXt multiple. The question is in which cases is it required? I think maybe I could avoid features that require multiple runs and keep the `--once` option to gain better performance. These multiple run seem like a huge waste.

Comment: Cross references and MetaFun overlays require at least two passes.

Comment: @HenriMenke What is cross reference and what is overlay in MetaFun?

Comment: if you refer to a section number later in the document, this will not be known on the first pass. If you have a table of contents at the start the page numbers are not known the first time ....

Comment: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/References, https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays

Comment: @HenriMenke What exactly will result in a problem? An overlay with MetaFun code inside or an overlay inside MetaFun code? Or just overlay itself? I'm no sure how MetaFun nad overlays are connected.

Comment: @Gherman Usually one uses MetaFun to draw boxes around text in an overlay, although MetaFun is not a requirement for overlays.

Comment: @HenriMenke MetaFun itself works for me with `once` just fine. What exactly case doesn't? MetaFun inside Overlay?

Comment: @Gherman Read the [MetaFun manual](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf).